# Will modules in c++20 reduce compile time compared to traditional header-files?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

Suppose we have the module interface source file foo.ixx in which the module foo is defined. We use

```
import foo;
```

in many different cpp-files. Will there be compile time reduction compared to the case where a traditional header-file foo.h is included in many different cpp-files? If the compile time is reduced, why is this the case?

Comment: The real question is: can they outperform precompiled headers?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Why do they need to?  They’re much more flexible and better behaved (not to mention standardized), so if they have even comparable performance that’s a win.

Comment: That's what they are telling us but a toy project here is actually slower to rebuild with modules. Perhaps I am doing something wrong (e.g. module per class).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, one of the advantages of modules is that it can reduce compilation times. For comparison, here's how it's done today:

```
// foo.hpp
// some code
```

```
// a.cpp
#include "foo.hpp"
```

```
// b.cpp
#include "foo.hpp"
```

Now when the 2 translation units `a.cpp` and `b.cpp` are compiled, `some code` is textually included into these source files, and hence `some code` is compiled twice. While the linker will take care that only one definition is actually in the final executable, the compiler still has to compile `some code` twice, which is wasted effort.

With modules, we would have something like:

```
// foo.hpp
export module foo;
// some code
```

```
// a.cpp 
import foo;
```

```
// b.cpp 
import foo;
```

Now the compilation process is different; there is an intermediate stage where `foo.hpp` is compiled into a format that is consumable by `a.cpp`, and `b.cpp`, which means that the implementation files do not need to compile `some code`, they can just use the definitions in `some code` directly.

This means that the `foo.hpp` only needs to be compiled once, which can lead to potentially large reductions in compile times, especially as the number of implementation files that consume the module interface unit increases.

Comment: To be fair, pure LTO mode which is getting ever more common means the code is not fully compiled until the end, thus discarding any duplicates before that expensive stage.

Comment: For anyone who tries to google what LTO is, it is Link Time Optimization, and here is the doc from LLVM: https://llvm.org/docs/LinkTimeOptimization.html

Answer (score 2):

"The mechanism for accessing headers from implementation files is to use the include directive from the C preprocessor. In other words, your headers are implicitly copied many times.

There are many copies of all header files scattered across a project, and the compiler has to pass through and parse them over and over again. One of the most visible problems is code compilation times.

Modules effectively replace header files and the preprocessor include directive. The solution proposed by modules suggests that we get rid of textual inclusion with the C preprocessor and, therefore, all of its drawbacks." [Each module handled just once. See Table 2]

[image]

[Reference](https://www.esrlabs.com/journal/c++20-modules/)

Answer (score 0):

Header include mechanism relies on text preprocessing (essentially similar to interpreted scripting languages); which is both time-consuming and pron to hard to trace errors due to programmer mistakes.
The module import mechanism - on the other hand - is a much smarter mechanism for separating interface and implementation with better guarantee for consistency and correctness. It provides the means to define the interface and implementation in the same translation unit, leading to the possibility of matching the two and informing the lib developer of errors that would've been unnoticed in traditional include system. Thus, not only the build time, but also the entire development cycle is significantly shortened.